# Lua return value from callback

Tags: lua, callback, return, return-value, garrys-mod

I'm trying to get a value from a MySQL database query in lua, but cant seem to either return a value or set a local variable outside the callback either, the only progress I have made is being able to continuously pass the value through callbacks to where I need it but even then its still stuck in a callback and i'm unable to assign it to another variable.

This is what I currently have:

```
function Database:PrepareQuery(query, params, callback)
    local pq = DBObject:prepare(query)
    --pq:setOption(mysqloo.OPTION_NUMERIC_FIELDS) 

    -- Callback functions
    pq.onSuccess = function(data)
        print("Prepared Query successful!")
        pcall(callback, data:getData())
    end

    pq.onError = function(err)
        print("Prepared Query Error:", err)
    end

    -- Prepare the parameters
    local paramsType = type(params)
    if (params == NULL) then
        pq:setNull(1)
    elseif (paramsType == "number") then
        pq:setNumber(1, params)
    elseif (paramsType == "string") then
        pq:setString(1, params)
    elseif (paramsType == "boolean") then
        pq:setBoolean(1, params)
    elseif (paramsType == "table") then
        for k, v in ipairs(params) do
            if (v == NULL) then
                pq:setNull(k)
            else
                local vType = type(v)
                if (vType == "number") then
                    pq:setNumber(k, v)
                elseif (vType == "string") then
                    pq:setString(k, v)
                elseif (vType == "boolean") then
                    pq:setBoolean(k, v)
                end
            end
        end
    end

    -- Execute the query
    pq:start()
end

function DatabaseFuncs:GetCharacterName(steam_id64, callback)
    local query = [[
        SELECT 
            `character`.`first_name`,
            `character`.`last_name`
        FROM
            `character`
        WHERE
            `character`.`steam_id64` = ?
        ;
    ]]
    NYCRP.DB:PrepareQuery(query, steam_id64, function(result)
        callback(result[1].first_name.." "..result[1].last_name)
    end)
end
```

And I can call this like:

```
DatabaseFuncs:GetCharacterName(ply:SteamID64(), function(characterName)
    print(characterName)
end)
```

But I cant assign characterName to another variable, I want to be able to do this:

```
local characterName = DatabaseFuncs:GetCharacterName(ply:SteamID64())
```

Which means I need to return a value like this:

```
function DatabaseFuncs:GetCharacterName(steam_id64)
    local query = [[
        SELECT 
            `character`.`first_name`,
            `character`.`last_name`
        FROM
            `character`
        WHERE
            `character`.`steam_id64` = ?
        ;
    ]]
    local name
    NYCRP.DB:PrepareQuery(query, steam_id64, function(result)
        name = result[1].first_name.." "..result[1].last_name
    end)
    return name
end
```

But that does not work, any help please?

Comment: Your function exits before query result is ready, so `name` is `nil` on exiting.

Comment: Yes, the mysql connection is asynchronous, so it's not possible then to return any value from the callback or assign it to another variable then?

Comment: You'd better return the getter function instead of the value: replace `return name` with `local function get_name() return name end; return get_name` and rename your variable `characterName` to `getCharacterName` and in the outer code access `getCharacterName()` instead of `characterName`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thanks for the help, but after making the changes i'm getting nil returned

Comment: ok, another way is to insert your code which needs `name` in the body of callback function.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks yes that seems to be the only way but leads to a bit of callback hell and i'm not fond of how the code looks when done like that, until i can find a nicer solution i'll use the built in SQLite instead which doesn't have this issue and code looks better